# ERROR Unable to locate parameter named [total_recods] in JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to return an integer from "total_recods"(query type) on this method getDataCount().How to get total_recods as an integer?
I edit my code but it return 0 while I have some data in my database.

```
@Override
    public int getDataCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Query query=null;
        int count=0;

        try {
            query= em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) AS total_recods FROM Data");
            count = ((Number) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();

           logger.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS,count);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());

        }

         return count;

    }
```

**After I solve my problem,code look like this:**
**Hint:type of count sholud be long**

```
@Override
public long getDataCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    long count=0;

    try {
        count = (long)em.createQuery("select count(*) from Data")
                .getSingleResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, e.getMessage());

    }

     return count;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discarded the result. This is how you should do it:

```
query= em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM Data");
int count = ((Number) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Noticed that I used `Number`, because some database return `Long` while other return a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I edit my code when i see your solution but it gives me an error: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException&#x3a; could not extract ResultSet.Thanks!

Comment: Again nothing,i will do debugg now.Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I solve my problem.Thank you very much!I check the example and type of count should be long.

Comment: That's why I said to cast it as Number.

Comment: Yes,you have right,and you have noticed that before but i was thinking that the problem is on query.

Answer (score 0):

You may write `query.getParameter("total_recods",Integer.class);`

For more details read this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: I try your solution and again can not return me an integer values. Thanks!

Comment: What type returns? What value returns?  If you need primitives type int, you may write `query.getParameter("total_recods",Integer.class).intValue()`;

Comment: It returns nothing,but when I print count value inside catch(), count value is 0,while i have data in my database and it gives me an error,could  not  could not extract ResultSet. Can you edit my code and post in your answer if you can please?Thanks!

Comment: There is no "declared parameter" in the query, so no way you can "get" a parameter which doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The query does NOT have a PARAMETER called *total_recods*. It is a NATIVE query that has NO parameters. JPQL can have (named) PARAMETERS. This is SQL, and that uses NUMBERED PARAMETERS ONLY (and your SQL doesn't have any).

If you meant to get the result of the query then look at the `query.getSingleResult` return value!